# How to Disable root Frame when Another is Open in Swing java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, multiple-instances

I have one `JFrame` and in that I have 10 `JLabel` which will open new `JFrame`. that `JFrame` is Same that will open in 10 label but how to Disable that root `JFrame` when the Another `JFrame` is open and Enable that Root `JFrame` when that new frame is Closed?
Can I have your Suggestion please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use multiple JFrames. An application should only have a single JFrame.

For secondary windows you should use a `modal JDialog`. A modal JDialog will not allow you to click on the parent JFrema until the dialog is closed.

Comment: Well that is Right :) +1 for good idea but i have already used Secod Frame :(

Comment: @Krishna, then change it. Its one line of code to use a JDialog instead of a JFrame. Or you can write dozens of lines of code to try to make your JFrame modal. I don't know how to do that. Good luck.

Comment: Can u give me one example??